# Allow closing "Increase the chances..." tooltip/div notification

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

In SO Teams you are allowed to "increase the chances of getting an answer by notifying team members"  This is ok to see for new users, however, expert users don't need to see this any longer.

Suggestion is to make it closeable / cookieable or make it go away eventually based on how long the user was created?

As shown:

[image]

Above pictured: freehand X to give you an idea.